# How to switch shader programs in glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl, volume, raycasting

I want to do volume rendering using programmable pipeline (using glsl) and no fixed pipelines. I implement it with 2 passes with 2 shader programs, `exitPointProg` and `rayCastProg`. the first pass is to get the exit points (i.e. the back face) of a cube bounding box which will be used as a texture in the next pass which doing the raycasting. the idea to do the raycasting volume rendering comes from [here](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~trier/?page_id=98). I think I have done the most of the things right cause I have implemented this with fixed pipeline combined with the programmable pipeline. the things that confused me is that I achieved the result with the very first frame, and with a flash the display on the screen turn totally white (I set the `glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)`. I think there maybe some wrong with the switch of the shader programs or the FBO. here is what I do in the render() function.

1. 1st pass, render to a fbo with `exitPoints` texture bound to it to get the exit points of cube bounding box, using shader program `exitPointProg`.
2. 2ed pass, mapped the `exitPoints` texture (bound to `GL_TEXTURE1`) into the shader program `rayCastProg` as a uniform sampler2D variable which will used in the shader.
   here is the `setupFBO` and `render` and two subroutines:
   the `setupFBO()` function:

   ```
   void SimpleRayCasting::setupFBO()
   {
       GLuint textureHandles[1];
       glGenTextures(1, textureHandles);
       entryPoints = textureHandles[0];


       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, exitPoints);
       glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);


       GLuint depthRenderBuffer;
       glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderBuffer);
       glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);
       glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);

       glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
       glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                       exitPoints, 0/* level */);
       glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
                       depthRenderBuffer);


       checkFramebufferState(__FILE__, __LINE__);
       GLenum drawbufs[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
       glDrawBuffers(1, drawbufs);
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
   }
   ```

   the `render()` function:

   ```
   void SimpleRayCasting::render()
   {
       getExitPoints();
       GLUtils::checkForOpenGLError(__FILE__,__LINE__);
       rayCasting();
       GLUtils::checkForOpenGLError(__FILE__,__LINE__);
   }
   ```

   the `getExitPoints()` function:

   ```
   void SimpleRayCasting::getExitPoints() 
   {
       // render to the texture
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
       glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
       glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
       // checkFramebufferState(__FILE__, __LINE__); 
       glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0);
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
       exitPointsProg.use();
       // note that the model will recalculated.
       model = mat4(1.0f);
       model *= glm::rotate(angle , vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
       model *= glm::rotate(90.0f, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
       model *= glm::translate(vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f));
       view = glm::lookAt(vec3(0.0f,0.0f,2.0f), vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
       projection = mat4(1.0f);
       projection = glm::perspective(60.0f, (float)width/(float)height,0.01f, 400.0f);   
       setMatrices(exitPointsProg);
       glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
       glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
       drawBoundBox();
       glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
   }
   ```

   the `rayCasting` function:

   ```
   void SimpleRayCasting::rayCasting()
   {
       // Directly render to the screen
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
       glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
       glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
       glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0);
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |  GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
       rayCastProg.use();
       model = mat4(1.0f);
       model *= glm::rotate(angle, vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
       model *= glm::rotate(90.0f, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
       model *= glm::translate(vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f));
       view = glm::lookAt(vec3(0.0f,0.0f,2.0f), vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
       projection = mat4(1.0f);
       projection = glm::perspective(60.0f, (float)width/(float)height,0.01f, 400.0f);   
       setMatrices(rayCastProg);
       rayCastProg.setUniform("StepSize", stepSize);
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, exitPoints);
       rayCastProg.setUniform("ExitPoints", 1);
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, volume_to);
       rayCastProg.setUniform("VolumeTex", 4);
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, transferFunc_to);
       rayCastProg.setUniform("TransferFunc", 5);
       glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
       glCullFace(GL_BACK);
       drawBoundBox();
       glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
   }
   ```

   I am using a class inherited from QGLWidget in Qt. As I have mentioned early, I got the right result with just the 1st frame and quickly it flash away and turn totally white. I don't know what's wrong with this, is there something wrong with the switch of the shader program or the FBO thing? I have been working on this a long time and can't figure it out, any help will be appreciated!

**edit to ask**
is there any demo or tutorial demonstrate how to use multiple glsl shader programs with FBO?

Comment: This code is pretty dirty.  However, I suspect the problem concerns the glDrawBuffers(...) calls; you're never resetting them.  Also, you're never changing back to the first texture with glActiveTexture(...).  Other than that, I recommend modularizing everything so you can see what's going on.

Comment: @IanMallett It said that `The state set by glDrawBuffers is part of the FBO (or default framebuffer). So you can generally set this up once and leave it set.` frome [opengl official](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Multiple_Render_Targets) and I add the `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` at the end of function `getExitPoints()` and `render()`, but nothing differently happens.

Comment: It costs me a few days to figure it out, My code works great on my friend's GTX 570 card, but not on my APU 3500 (AMD Radeon HD 6620G). Finally I find it something wrong with my fragment shader corresponding to  my `rayCasting()` function. I didn't use the `Vertex Color` in the fragment shader first. After I add `Color` (`Color = VertexColor` in vertex shader)in fragment shader like this: `FragColor = colorAcum + (vec4(Color, 1.0) * 0.0);`. It works and I don't know why!